# Выделение текста в label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть текст в Ladel.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='LABEL')
label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Как сделать, чтобы можно было его выделить для последующего копирования в буфер обмена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего эмулировать с помощью `Entry`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Test')
label.pack()

s = tk.StringVar()
s.set('Test')
entry = tk.Entry(root, text=s, state='readonly', justify='center', bd=0)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```